# Group and differ array multiple item in another array

Tags: javascript

This my array:

```
diffList = [
    {group: "one", version: 1.1, old: 0.1},
    {group: "two", version: 2.1, old: 1.1},
    {group: "one", version: 1.2, old: 0.2},
    {group: "one", version: 1.3, old: 0.3}
    {group: "one", version: 1.4, old: 1.4}
    {group: "three", version: 3.1, old: 3.1}
    {group: "four", version: 4.1, old: 4.1}

]
```

I want to convert into this (need to retrieve only the bigger and smaller version) and push only the difference versions (expected):

```
myArray = [
 {group: "one", recentVersion: 1.4, oldVersion:0.1 }
 {group: "two", recentVersion: 2.1, oldVersion:1.1}
 // don't push goup three and four because version same
```

]

What I'm doing :

```
const groups = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < diffList.length; i++) {
        const groupName = diffList[i].group;
        if (!groups[groupName]) {
            groups[groupName] = {
                recentVersion: diffList[i].version,
                oldVersion: diffList[i].old,
            };
        }
        if (groups[groupName].recentVersion < diffList[i].version) {
            groups[groupName].recentVersion = diffList[i].version;
        }
        if (groups[groupName].oldVersion > diffList[i].old) {
            groups[groupName].oldVersion = diffList[i].version;
        }
    }
    let myArray = [];
    for (const groupName in groups) {
        myArray.push({
            group: groupName,
            recentVersion: groups[groupName].recentVersion,
            oldVersion: groups[groupName].oldVersion,
        });
    }
    console.log(myArray);
```

Result:

```
myArray = [
 {group: "one", recentVersion: 1.4, oldVersion:0.1 }
 {group: "two", recentVersion: 2.1, oldVersion:1.1},
 {group: "three", recentVersion: 3.1, oldVersion:3.1},
 {group: "four", recentVersion: 4.1, oldVersion:4.1}
]
```

When I need to specified the condition for the difference in my script ...

Answer (score 0):

Anyway. Check if same versions and omit the pushing.

```
for (const groupName in groups) {
    // add a check in advance for same versions
    if (groups[groupName].recentVersion === groups[groupName].oldVersion) continue;

    myArray.push({
        group: groupName,
        recentVersion: groups[groupName].recentVersion,
        oldVersion: groups[groupName].oldVersion,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try my code:

```
let diffList = [
    {group: "one", version: 1.1, old: 0.1},
    {group: "two", version: 2.1, old: 1.1},
    {group: "one", version: 1.2, old: 0.2},
    {group: "one", version: 1.3, old: 0.3},
    {group: "one", version: 1.4, old: 1.4},
    {group: "three", version: 3.1, old: 3.1},
    {group: "four", version: 4.1, old: 4.1},
]
let groups = []
diffList.map(l => {
  if (groups.find(g => g.group === l.group)) {

  } else groups.push({group: l.group})
})
groups.map(g => {
  let arr_filter = diffList.filter(d => d.group === g.group)
  arr_filter.sort((a,b) =>{
    return b.version - a.version
  })

  g.recentVersion = arr_filter[0].version
  arr_filter.sort((a,b) =>{
    return a.old - b.old
  })
  g.oldVersion = arr_filter[0].old
})
console.log(groups.filter(g => g.recentVersion != g.oldVersion))
```

This is the [demo](https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/PoqOoRd)